# VB.NET Returns IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T)) when Using Group By LINQ Statement

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

I am trying to convert [Anthyme Caillard's `INotifyDataErrorInfo` implementation](http://burnaftercoding.com/post/asynchronous-validation-with-wpf-4-5/) into VB.NET. All goes well until I reach the `Validate` method, which has the following LINQ query, in which `q` is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ValidationResult>>`:

```cs
var q = from r in validationResults
        from m in r.MemberNames
        group r by m into g
        select g;
```

I have tried the following translation:

```vb
Dim q = From r In valResults
        From m In r.MemberNames
        Group r By r.MemberNames Into Group
        Select Group
```

Or even the lambda expression version, (assuming I'm using [John Skeet's syntax](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/) correctly):

```vb
Dim q = valResults.GroupBy(Function(r) r, Function(r) r.MemberNames)
```

but in both of these, `q` is of type `IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of ValidationResult))`.

I have looked at [VB and IGrouping for LINQ Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921616/vb-and-igrouping-for-linq-query) and [VB.Net - Linq Group By returns IEnumerable(Of Anonymous Type)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8ffed7e-00a3-4be9-afe7-1fccb3bce377/vbnet-linq-group-by-returns-ienumerableof-anonymous-type), but I don't think they apply since I will be working with the group directly, and not a specialized class.

Why aren't these implementations returning the same thing, and what can I do to make `q` the required `IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of String, ValidationResult))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the VB compiler treats LINQ query syntax different than the C# compiler.

In C# the expression

```c#
from element in list
group element by element.Value
```

is identical to

```c#
list.GroupBy(element => element.Value)
```

In VB however

```
From element In list
Group element By element.Value Into g = Group
```

is translated into

```
list.GroupBy(Function(element) element.Value,
             Function(key, element) New With { Key .Value = key, Key .g = element })
```

I can't see any good reason why the VB compiler introduces an anonymous type here - but that's what it does.

I recommend you always translate C# LINQ query syntax (`from a in list select a.Value`) into a method chain (`list.Select(a => a.Value)`). That way the VB compiler can't interfere. It is forced to use the exact chain of methods.

However your translation of the original query isn't correct.

```c#
var q = from r in validationResults
        from m in r.MemberNames
        group r by m into g
        select g;
```

is actually translated into

```c#
var q = validationResults.SelectMany(r => r.MemberNames, (r, m) => new { r, m })
                         .GroupBy(t => t.m, t => t.r);
```

which in VB becomes:

```
Dim q = validationResults.SelectMany(Function(r) r.MemberNames,
                                     Function(r, m) New With { Key .r = r, Key .m = m }) _
                         .GroupBy(Function(t) t.m, Function(t) t.r)
```