# LINQ - Group By - IEnumerable return

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm returning a IEnumerable in my function, but I now need to Group my result by a number (UitleenbonNR).  For the rest I want to have the same IEnumerable back, not a list or whatever, just the same IEnumerable as before my Group by query.
In SQL this would be very easy, but with LINQ I can't seem to find the solution.

My working function is the following:

```
 Public Function GetUitleenbonnen(ByVal bon As String, ByVal ontlener As String, ByVal asset As String) As IEnumerable(Of tblUitleenbon)
    dc = New BradyL2S(General.dblocation)


    Dim results = From a In dc.tblUitleenbons

    If bon <> "" Then
        results = From a In results Where a.UitleenbonNaam.Contains(bon)
    End If

    If ontlener <> "" Then
        results = From a In results Where a.UitleenbonOntlenerNaam.Contains(ontlener)
    End If

    If asset <> "" Then
        results = From a In results Where a.UitleenbonAssetNaam.Contains(asset)
    End If

    results = From a In results Order By a.UitleenbonNR Ascending
    Return results
End Function
```

So in the last line, the Order By should change to the Group By clause.
I have tried a lot of different things, but I got no luck with neither.

```
        results = From a In results Group a By a.UitleenbonNR
```

or

```
        results = From a In results Group a By a.UitleenbonNR Into anr = Group
```

or so many other options, but all of them failed.
Any suggestion what I can do to do a Group By, and get a IEnumerable in return?

Thanks

Comment: How are they failing?  What errors?

Comment: There is an issue in assigning the group back to `results` because once you group `IEnumerable(Of a)` you can't have `IEnumerable(Of a)` anymore because groups are by definition multiple of multiple things. So instead of assigning back to results you should start with `Dim value = From a In ...` and see what type value is. [VB.Net is notoriously bad with query expression grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53940584/832052), hence my lambda solution

Comment: What does "For the rest I want to have the same IEnumerable back" mean - returning the same `IEnumerable` would mean just not doing the `GroupBy`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda to group, I think it's cleaner than query expression for GroupBy

```vb
Return results.GroupBy(Function(a) a.UitleenbonNR)
```

and the return type of the function is

```vb
IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Integer, tblUitleenbon))
```

(assuming UitleenbonNR is an Integer)

Comment: I get an error message when I try this: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Decimal,Brady_Management.tblUitleenbon]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,Brady_Management.tblUitleenbon]]

UitleenbonNR is indeed an integer.